# Why is the linear functional $F:C[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $F(f)=\int f d\mu$ continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, linear-transformations

Let $\mu$ be a finite, Borel measure, and let $[a,b]$ be a closed, bounded interval on $\mathbb{R}$.

Why is the linear functional $F:C[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $F(f)=\int f d\mu$ continuous?

First of all, I see that:

$$|F(f)| = |\int f d\mu| \leq \int |f| d\mu \leq ||f||_{\infty} \mu([a,b]) $$

... where $||f||_{\infty} = max\{|f(x)|:x \in [a,b]\}$, and so this is just the M-L inequality.

It is said that a linear functional is continuous iff it is bounded. However, I don't see why this one is continous, since the above computation is just for a single function $f$, and this isn't a bound for all $f$. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You proved correctly that $\bigl|F(f)\bigr|\leqslant\|f\|_\infty\mu\bigl([a,b]\bigr)$. Therefore, $\|f\|_\infty=1\implies\bigl|F(f)\bigr|\leqslant\mu\bigl([a,b]\bigr)$. So, $F$ is a bounded linear map.

Comment: I believe you mean $\|F\| \le \mu(a,b)$ after $\implies$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts No. What I wrote was what I meant to write. Of course, it follows from that tha $\|F\|\leqslant\mu\bigl([a,b]\bigr)$.

Answer (score 0):

The operator norm is 
$$
\sup_{f\neq 0}\frac{|F(f)|}{\lVert f\rVert_{\infty}}
$$
which is bounded by $\mu[a,b]$